# How to detect slow internet connections in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using a React Native app built with expo. I wanted to know how to detect slow internet connection using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using expo then you can check the netinfo docs, where type of connection will give an approx of network speed. [expo netinfo](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/netinfo/)

If you want to check the network status that suddenly it went down or offline you can use the react-native-offline library as it constantly pings and checks , and its documentation is good . [react-native-offline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-offline)